Sometimes in Space Invaders JS I shoot two aliens when the shoot hits the same time aliens shift
I would be very grateful for any help, trying to code Space Invaders in JS, managed to move aliens in functions to shift the board right left and down in Intervals, the laser shoot is also in another Interval moving it up.
The problem that sometimes when the laser hits the exact time aliens are shifting it shoots two aliens, and my alien counter on the screen doesn't match the actual seen on the game, and cant finish the game, i finish the game according to the global var aliens counter, is it a problem of Intervals, or handleHit function I am not sure.
https://github.com/Farhan-Ganayim/Space-Invaders
https://farhan-ganayim.github.io/Space-Invaders/
I managed to shoot aliens and the score is fine, that happens when play game with slow aliens and shoot them accurately, but when setting the interval to 1 sec, sometimes the problem of shooting two aliens happens.
function handleAlienHit(pos) {
    
    // clearInterval(laserInterval)
    // updateCell(pos,null)
    gGame.alienCount--    
    updateScore()
    gHero.isShoot=false  
}

function blinkLaser(pos) {
    // var cellGameObject=gBoard[pos.i][pos.j].gameObject
    updateCell(pos, LASER)
    setTimeout(() => {
        updateCell(pos, null)
    }, 80)
}


Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask] pages.  Please add all the relevant code to the question, not just with links to code that will change over time.   Please read: can I just link to my code/site

Without seeing the code, it would be a guess that the handleAlienHit is in the wrong interval or there is some other code that determines the alientCount.   I would expect to see the alientCount-- in the same segment of code that removes the alien (not necessarily the code that updates the UI, but the back-end part that tracks the aliens).

You might also like to consider an alternative to using multiple timers - eg using a game "tick" timer and updating everything within that tick - eg aliens move every 50th tick, laser moves every 20th tick, fast aliens move every 10th tick.

Thanks for responding, alientCount-- is in hanleAlienHit function itself, don't understand what you mean by ticks but i run them in Interval using setInterval(), aliens move every 1 sec and laser blinks up every80 ms

Don't keep track of the alien count manually. I would just keep an array of living aliens. When this length is 0, they are all dead. This is way easier of you use OOP btw.

Please read: Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?

Full reproducible code needs to be in the question itself.

You are passing a position object by reference as if it had value semantics.
function blinkLaser(pos) {

    updateCell(pos, LASER)
    setTimeout(() => {
        updateCell(pos, null)  // <-- Oops! The properties of pos may have changed!
    }, 80)
}

pos is an object that you defined in your shoot function (it's called laserPos in that code).  You reuse this same object in all cases where a position is used, but you modify its properties by calling laserPos.i--.
That means that it's possible that the properties of pos can be changed after you call updateCell(pos, LASER) but before the timeout elapses.  Then, since updateCell(pos, null) is referring to the one-and-only position object, but its properties have changed, your blinkLaser function isn't updating the screen properly.
Copy the position
You could fix this by writing updateCell({ ...pos }, null)  to make a shallow copy of the position object so that you null out the same position that you updated earlier in the function at updateCell(pos, LASER).

Thanks a lot for your effort, I figured out the problem, in my blinkLaser function i used updateCell() function that updates the Model and the DOM, well blinkLaser function is responsible of blinking the laser and should not use UpdateCell(), i need to update the cell in the handleAlienHit and other functions that really handle the MODEL and DOM,

blinkLaser() is just a graphical effect function that should not change the MODEL
